# Execute Java class using groovy code

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am trying to execute a java .class file using groovy script :

```
    def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
    def proc = "java ${fileName}".execute()
    proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
    proc.waitFor()
    println "out> $sout err> $serr"
```

It gives error: `err> Error: Could not find or load main class cle47d1d78d99a44a8ba01f0bc7612ad16` (class name generated using uuid). But when I execute it in bash it gives proper output. I checked filename, pwd and ensured that the .class file exist in the folder where groovy tries to execute command.

I am able to run other commands and also compile .java file successfully using:

```
def proc = "javac ${file.path}".execute()
```

Please suggest.

Comment: How did you compile the java file? did you declare any main method that executes the code

Comment: Is there a special reason why you fork the JVM (running a separate java program) ?
It will be much faster to load the java class in the initial classpath or use a URLClassLoader to load it (and then run the main method using reflection)

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I compiled the .java file using javac command through groovy and then I am trying to execute it.

Comment: @Benoît I am trying to automate the process of evaluating java code.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of ${fileName} . I think it contains value like "ABC.java" . Where as you must use command "java ${className}".

```
Use:

java ${className}

ex:
If com.abc.ABC is the class containing the main function
java com.abc.ABC
```

Package is also necessary

Comment: Could you share class you are trying to exectute